# Auto register Func<T> for .net core dependecy injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

The default [.net core dependency injection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/) doesn't support building Func<> for injection automatically, see [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35736070).  I wrote an extension method to go find all the Func in register types constructors and build the Func automatically, needs to be called at end of registrations.

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    private static MethodInfo GetServiceMethod;

    static ServiceCollectionExtensions()
    {
        Func<IServiceProvider, object> getServiceMethod = ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService<object>;
        GetServiceMethod = getServiceMethod.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers all Funcs in constructors to the ServiceCollection - important to call after all registrations
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="collection"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IServiceCollection AddFactories(this IServiceCollection collection)
    {
        // Get a list of all Funcs used in constructors of regigstered types
        var funcTypes = new HashSet<Type>(collection.Where(x => x.ImplementationType != null)
            .Select(x => x.ImplementationType)
            .SelectMany(x => x.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
            .SelectMany(x => x.GetParameters())
            .Select(x => x.ParameterType)
            .Where(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Func<>)));

        // Each func build the factory for it
        foreach (var funcType in funcTypes)
        {
            var type = funcType.GetGenericArguments().First();
            collection.AddTransient(funcType, FuncBuilder(type));
        }

        return collection;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This build expression tree for a func that is equivalent to 
    ///     Func<IServiceProvider, Func<TType>> factory = serviceProvider => new Func<TType>(serviceProvider.GetService<TType>);
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static Func<IServiceProvider, object> FuncBuilder(Type type)
    {
        var serviceProvider = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IServiceProvider), "serviceProvider");
        var method = GetServiceMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type);
        var call = Expression.Call(method, serviceProvider);
        var returnType = typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(type);
        var returnFunc = Expression.Lambda(returnType, call);
        var func = Expression.Lambda(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(IServiceProvider), returnType), returnFunc, serviceProvider);
        var factory = func.Compile() as Func<IServiceProvider, object>;
        return factory;
    }
}
```

I register the Funcs as Transient but I think it would have been safe to register them as singleton.  Not sure which has more overhead.

For a simple test

```
public interface ITransient
{
    Guid Id { get; }
}

public class Transient : ITransient
{
    public Transient()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
    public Guid Id { get; }
}

public class SingleTon
{
    private readonly Func<ITransient> _transientFunc;
    public SingleTon(Func<ITransient> transientFunc)
    {
        _transientFunc = transientFunc;
    }

    public ITransient GetTransient()
    {
        return _transientFunc();
    }
}
```

If the func isn't working correctly I would get the same object each time back on the transient class.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    serviceCollection.AddSingleton<SingleTon>();
    serviceCollection.AddTransient<ITransient, Transient>();
    serviceCollection.AddFactories();
    var container = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

    var singleton = container.GetService<SingleTon>();
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(singleton.GetTransient(), singleton.GetTransient()))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    Console.ReadLine();
    container.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Singletons should not depend on transients

Comment: I understand that is the guideline.  I also agree with that guideline but sometimes you do need to have other classes used and either you can inject a func which you can sub out during testing or you have to use the service locator pattern.

Comment: I added another answer to the question you referenced. I don't understand why the answers say that you can't register a function (although I recommend a delegate) because you can. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35736070/how-to-use-funct-in-built-in-dependency-injection/53964998#53964998

Comment: It's pretty bad that it relies on the parameter name as a hardcoded string. Isn't it possible to avoid somehow?

Comment: It doesn't. It's looking for func sig

Comment: You must understand that this is a very terrible solution. It will introduce a very high performance cost (due to the reflection). The bigger the application i.e. exponentially the more classes are registered with one or more `Func<T>`. I really don't recommend this solution. This feature isn't offered because Microsoft doesn't know how to implement it. It has terrible performance overhead which will drastically slow down application startup. Better don't be lazy and register the delegates explicitly. This example uses heavy reflection and iterations.

Comment: For more complex delegates, like a `Func<TParam, TResult>` it is recommended to either create a dedicated delegate or an abstract factory.

Comment: Reflection isn't generally bad if used sparingly. But in context of DI in a big application (this is where DI is usually used) we must expect hundreds and more factory delegates and types with huge constructors (in terms of parameter count). This can and will quickly escalate.

Comment: This question is 3 years ago.  But even then, I would still do this.  This is a onetime reflection hit during startup.